# insert date difference in last column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to insert date difference of 4th and 5th column in the 6th column but it is giving me error saying column not allowed.

```
insert into leave25 vALUES (4, 4, 'SICK', TO_DATE('22-AUG-14','DD-MON-YY'),  TO_DATE('22-SEP-14','DD-MON-YY'), startdate-enddate)\\
```

Answer (score 3):

Always specify the column names explicitly in your `INSERT` statements. It is **safer** that way.

If you want to avoid writing the dates again, you could select the values from a subquery.

```
INSERT INTO leave25 
            (col1, 
             col2, 
             col3, 
             startdate, 
             enddate,
             days) 
SELECT t.*, 
       startdate - enddate 
FROM   (SELECT 4, 
               4, 
               'SICK', 
               to_date('22-AUG-14', 'DD-MON-YY') as startdate, 
               to_date('22-SEP-14', 'DD-MON-YY') as enddate
        FROM   dual) t;
```

Furthermore, I agree with Aleksej, it is better to have this difference stored as a **[virtual column](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1)** rather than a column itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can not do it this way, you need to esplicitly use the values you want to insert:

```
INSERT INTO leave25
     VALUES (
             4,
             4,
             'SICK',
             TO_DATE('22-AUG-14', 'DD-MON-YY'),
             TO_DATE('22-SEP-14', 'DD-MON-YY'),
             TO_DATE('22-SEP-14', 'DD-MON-YY') - TO_DATE('22-AUG-14', 'DD-MON-YY')
```

Besides, if this column always contains that difference, are you sure you need to store this redundant information?

A different approach could be by using a trigger to populate that column without explicitly giving it a value, but this depends on your environment and your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Use a virtual column:

```
CREATE TABLE Leave25(
  EMPLOYEEID INTEGER
             CONSTRAINT LEAVE25__EMPID__FK REFERENCES Employee24,
  LEAVEID    INTEGER
             CONSTRAINT LEAVE25__LEAVEID__PK PRIMARY KEY,
  LEAVETYPE  VARCHAR2(20)
             CONSTRAINT LEAVE25__LEAVETYPE__NN NOT NULL
             CONSTRAINT LEAVE25__LEAVETYPE__CHK CHECK (
               LEAVETYPE IN 'EARNED', 'SICK'
             ),
  STARTDATE  DATE
             CONSTRAINT LEAVE25__STARTDATE__NN NOT NULL,
  ENDDATE    DATE
             CONSTRAINT LEAVE25__ENDDATE__NN NOT NULL,
  DURATION   NUMBER
             GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( ENDDATE - STARTDATE ) VIRTUAL
);
```

And create a sequence to manage the primary key:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE LEAVE25__LEAVEID__SEQ;
```

Then you can do:

```
INSERT INTO leave25 (
  EMPLOYEEID, LEAVEID, LEAVETYPE, STARTDATE, ENDDATE
) VALUES (
  4, LEAVE25__LEAVEID__SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'SICK', DATE '2014-08-22', DATE '2014-09-22'
)
```